# I can't get .DXF 3D model to import properly

Tags: import

any help is appreciated, I'm very new to all this. I have Blender 3.2.2 installed on my laptop (Mac OS Monterey). I'm trying to import a 3D model from AutoCAD 2023 for Mac. I've made a copy of the original .DWG file and converted the copy to .DXF. I've also activated the two .DXF add-on's in Blender. However, when I go to import the .DXF file to Blender, all it imports is a couple of lines, as though most of the file (including shaded surfaces) has been erased. Is there any way to import a 3D model into Blender so that it retains full file integrity? If not I guess I'll try importing a 2D floor plan and extruding it in Blender.

Thanks again.

Comment: [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_dxf.html#autocad-dxf) is the Blender documentation on DXF importing showing what is included.

Comment: I would try a few things : Explode your model so it's only 3D faces in acad, not mesh or polyface. look for your model at very high coordinates, you can zoom to the extents of your objects with numpad .